# Running scala in cmd makes i look like I am missing 'build.sbt'

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-repl

I'm trying to run Scala in my command line.

I checked my java, went to the Scala website, downloaded and installed it, updated my environment variables.

So far the only thing different from guides online is that the folder where `sbt` is installed does not include a "lib" folder.

I then run `sbt` command in my prompt, and I get this message:

[image]

It looks like I'm missing a file called `build.sbt`, what is this? and do i need it?

Edit:

If I press 'continue' on the picture above, I get

```
sbt:scalaproj>
```

Which looks fine, but if i type some code, like this:

```
sbt:scalaproj> var a : Int = 12;
```

Then it returns errors:

```
[error] Expected ';'
[error] var a : Int = 12
```

What in the world is going wrong? can someone point me to a guide for writing Scala in the prompt that is not too old to work?

Comment: **sbt** is a project manager, you need a file called `build.sbt` that defines the project. If you only want to run a REPL shell it may be better to install **Scala** itself.

Comment: yes I thought so too, but it seems to me that sbt is the only scala thing that i am able to get on the scala website.

Comment: and also, this build.sbt-file where should i usually find it?

Comment: it is not something you find. You have to create it yourself in the root directory of your project. You will have specify your project name, version and dependencies in this file. You can go on github and look at any example project to see this file. 

But as @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez suggested, you should go with Scala REPL itself. If you scroll down on the scala website you will see **"Other ways to Install Scala"**

Comment: sbt is scala build tool which is used to build entire project. If you want to run only single scala file then use `scalac FileName.scala` and then `scala compiled_file`

Read this if you want to run project using sbt. 
https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/sbt-track/getting-started-with-scala-and-sbt-on-the-command-line.html

Comment: [Here](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/) you can find all the installers, including the windows `msi` - the `build.sbt` file has to be created by you for each project, is not that you find it in someplace, but that you run **sbt** over some project which has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first understand the terminology. Scala is the language you are writing. SBT is an acronym for Scala Build Tool. Both of them have REPL.

When you call `sbt` in the command line, you initiate the REPL of `sbt`. The commands you can run there, are all commands `sbt` supports. You can find [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Running.html#Common+commands) the common commands. For example, if you run compile, it will compile the `build.sbt` located at the directory where you called the `sbt` command. Anyway, Scala commands WILL NOT work here. Scala commands are not `sbt` commands.

In order to run Scala REPL, you need to type `console` in the `sbt` REPL. You can find here the [Scala REPL documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/scala-repl.html). Within the Scala REPL you can run Scala commands.

P.S.
You can find the Scala download page [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/).